# InDesign: generating an ICML file without style definition

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I'm writing a script (in a Node.js environment, but that's irrelevant to my question) to generate ICML files to be imported in Adobe InDesign. I will use a template (as simple as possible) into which the script will inject the data and save the output as an .icml file.

Each generated document will focus on the content (story) only, not the style definitions: I want it to *reference* styles so that the content is properly formatted in InDesign, but using styles defined in the InDesign document itself.

Which gives something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?aid style="50" type="snippet" readerVersion="6.0" featureSet="257" product="8.0(370)" ?>
<?aid SnippetType="InCopyInterchange"?>
<Document DOMVersion="8.0" Self="d">
  <Story Self="story">
    <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/TITLE">
      <Content>Hello world!</Content>
      <Br />
    </ParagraphStyleRange>
 </Story>
</Document>
```

The paragraph style `TITLE` is referenced here and defined in the InDesign document where I'll import this, but it doesn't work: the content is left unstyled.

Do you know how I can solve this? I hope this is not because styles *must* be defined in the icml document...

Comment: Have you tried adding `$ID` to the value of the `AppliedParagraphStyle` attribute: For instance: `<ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/$ID/TITLE">`

Comment: I've just tried and it seems to work!

Comment: Sorry, in fact it doesn't work. And I can't find documentation for this format. Can you explain what's $ID supposed to do?

Comment: This [PDF](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/idml/idml-specification.pdf) about _IDML_ contains info regarding _ICML_ (note: _ICML_ includes many elements identical to the  _IDML_ format). The `$ID` internal variable is not defined explicitly in this doc, however it shows references to it. Adding `$ID` to the value of the `AppliedParagraphStyle` attribute should work successfully, however  a matching named Paragraph Style must exist (e.g. `TITLE`) in your `.indd` or `.indt` file before importing the `.icml` file - it doesn't auto generate a new para style.

Comment: Thanks. I had this one. I'll do some more tests.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution. Tried out using AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/$ID/TITLE" but that didn't work.

Comment: @KeldJ No, I couldn't solve this problem, sorry.

Comment: I ended up getting an template ICML template containing all the paragraphstyles which i then manipulate using XmlDocument in C#